# tomcat server for setting java -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

Tags: tomcat, log4j

How can we set the tomcat server 7.0 (java 1.7) or tomcat application so that it is -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true  to avoid log4j vulnerability problems.

Should I just add to  $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how Tomcat is started. If the `startup.sh/catalina.sh` scripts are used (usual in Unix environments), then adding:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
```

in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` will work. If you are using Windows and start Tomcat as a service it will not.

An alternative universal way is to add a file `$CATALINA_BASE/lib/log4j2.component.properties` (see [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties); `log4j2.system.properties` will also work, but it is undocumented) and set:

```
log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
```

there.